# Rspec for cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cancan

I am not sure where I'll write test cases for our app, if i am using cacncan.

This should be in model or controller section.

In my case:

a user can delete or not a object.
To handle this case I used cancan and I think this code should be in model not in controller and how do I test this using rspec.

Please provide me a better advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the following approach:

1. Write unit tests for cancan's Ability class, to make sure your role logic is good.
2. Write controller tests for each scenario where someone can/cannot access that controller, according to your application's logic.
3. Write some acceptance/integrations tests that actually hit the page, to make sure authorization works end-to-end. Here you don't have to be as thorough as you should be in steps 1 and 2. You can test "sunny day" scenarios here, where you perform an action as the user of that level. You may want to add a few tests, around the critical parts of your app, where you login as the wrong level of user and try to do something that is not authorized.

Comment: I'd go with that, plus: don't try to put the cancan stuff in the model. It's not built for that.